# cron recently ignores changes to /etc/crontab

Tags: debian, cron, bug

Cron recently started to ignore any changes to `/etc/crontab`. Cron's mail works for the older entries. Restarting cron with `sudo systemctl restart cron` has no effect. I did not install new packages since it last worked properly. I do not want to restart my server to find out if that helps; that would just be a workaround anyway...

I use Debian 9.6 and Cron 3.0pl1-128+deb9u1.

Comment: Look for a syntax error in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me: I added another cronjob earlier where I tried to use a backslash to span a command over two lines which seems to be invalid syntax.

Comment: So maybe accept this answer.